# Pyramid security: how to detect authorization to a view in advance

Tags: python, authentication, authorization, pyramid

I have a pyramid application, using pyramid security: https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/security.html

It works fine, i.e. it protects my application exactly the way i mean it to do, but in order to know if "I" (the user) am authorized to a view, the only way *seems* to be going the view itself and get the not authorized page.

Is there a way to know *in advance* if a user is authorized to a view? This is useful in order to hide links the user is not authorized to.

For instance, in a view, I would like to have a method like:

```
some_authorization_object.authorized_to_view('view_name')
```

or something smilar.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not really enough code in your question to know how you have implemented your pyramid authentication and authorization policies, but one example of how to "know in advance if a user is authorized to a view" is to use the `effective_principals` from the request in your handler code. You can learn more about `pyramid.request.effective_principals` here: https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [request.has_permission](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.has_permission) (which used to be [pyramid.security.has_permission](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/security.html#pyramid.security.has_permission) in older verions of Pyramid). It works similarly to your imaginary example, only instead of the view name you need to pass it the context and the name of the permission you're checking:

```
if request.has_permission(context, 'access-site-settings'):
    show_site_settings_link = True
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the answerer's posts, i was able to devise a final solution.

The key to the final solution was the method request.registry.introspector.categorized() that gives a (quite complex but still readable) structure of views someway "joined" with permissions; this way it is possible to find the pemissions needed to see the view then, with the has_permission() method, it is finally possible to determine if the user has permission to the view.

The steps are the following:

- Acknowledge that there is a categorized structure of data, i.e.:
  `request.registry.introspector.categorized()`
- Get thedata source for permissions related to views, filtering with the view (view_name) we are interested in:

  ```
  # Get a list of views:
  views_list = [
      v for v in request.registry.introspector.categorized() if v[0] == 'views'
  ][0][1]
  # From the list, select the one with the name we are looking for:
  related_permissions_source = [
      v["related"] for v in views_list if
      view_name in v["introspectable"].discriminator
  ]
  ```
- Extract the list of permission names needed to see the view:

  `view_related_permissions = [
      rel for rel in related_permissions_source[0] if rel.category_name ==     "permissions"
  ]
  permission_names = [
      rper.discriminator for rper in view_related_permissions
  ]`
- Finally, for each element of the view_related_permissions, check if the current user is authorized:

  `request.has_permission(permission)`

The first occurrence the user has permission to states that the user has permissionto the view.

Comment: For inspiration you can also check Websauna's sitemap builder than scans all resources and attached views and check which have public permissions: https://websauna.org/docs/_modules/websauna/system/core/sitemap.html#ReflectiveSitemapBuilder

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare factory with acl permissions

```
class AdministrationFactory:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
        self.__acl__ = [
            (Allow, 'role:admin', ALL_PERMISSIONS),
            (Allow, 'role:administration', ('create', 'read', 'update'))
        ]


def administration_factory(request):
    return AdministrationFactory(request)
```

and in your routes pass the factory object

```
config.add_route('administration_team_index', '/administration/team', factory=administration_factory, request_method='GET')
```

Comment: So an how should the OP check whether they need to display a link to '/administration/team' from another page?

Comment: Yes. Pyramid was `request.has_permission()` that can be used in the context of traverable resources. https://websauna.org/docs/narrative/user/permissions.html?highlight=checking%20permission#manually-checking-a-permission